# Add content link not shown for custom content if not granted permission to create basic page or article

Tags: nodes

Hi all and first of all thanks for reading!!

I written a module that creates a custom content type and manages its permissions.

All works well for authenticated user whom i grant permissions to create and edit that custom content type, the only thing doesn't work is the "add content" link in menu navigation.

The authenticated user see the navigation menu and, if i copy and paste the link, is able to create custom content, but the link "add content" is not shown **unless** i grant permission also to create basic page or article page.
This is very confusing me.
Someone could help?

Many thanks.

Best regards.